# python where are the system packages installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

For example when i do

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

where does the system install scipy ? i did not found it in `/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

```
which python 
/opt/bitnami/python/bin/python/
```

where is it then ?

Comment: `/opt/bitnami` is a custom install, and it won't pick up system packages.

Comment: you are right, it is in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dpkg -L` command to know where the files are installed:

```
dpkg -L python-scipy
```

Comment: thank you !!! you really saved me. i was in some big issues and now i know the root problem

Comment: @RachidO., Why don't you use the system version of PYthon (`/usr/bin/python`) ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough: `python -c 'import scipy; print(scipy.__file__)'`.